# Swift - Get class name from MetaType?

Tags: swift

In the example below T refers to a type that extends NSManagedObject, so why can I not call.

**I do not have access to an instance of the class**

```
private func getNewManagedObject <T: NSManagedObject>(type: T.Type) -> T {

    // Let's assume all Entity Names are the same as Class names
    let className = "" /*Somehow get class name from type ("User")*/
    return NSEntityDescription.insertNewObjectForEntityForName(className, inManagedObjectContext: managedObjectContext) as T
}

getNewManagedObject(User.self);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Switf 2 solutions

```
let className = String(Int.self) // String

let className2 = String(4.dynamicType) // Int

func doThings<T>(type: T.Type) -> String {
    return String(T) // Whatever type passed
}
```

Comment: Swift 3 solutions

`let className = String(describing: Int.self) //String`

Answer (score 5):

Swift classes can be given a custom Objective-C name, what will make `NSStringFromClass` print a nicer output in a playground.

```
import CoreData

@objc(User) class User : NSManagedObject {

}

let className = NSStringFromClass(User.self) // className will be "User"
```

Without it, `NSStringFromClass` will print 'ModulName.ClassName' which is arguably better than 'ClassName' only. The ugliness of the playground output is due to the fact that playgrounds have some cryptic implicit module names.

Answer (score 4):

With some experimenting I found out the following. In Playground you can do

```
class User : NSManagedObject {
}

let s = NSStringFromClass(User)  // cryptic output: "__lldb_expr_XX.User"
```

The `XX` is some random number. At this point you can get the entity name with

```
let entityName = s.pathExtension // "User"
```

It's a bit hacky but maybe it could work for you.

Comment: Thanks, I'll look around to see if there is any better solution, if not I'll accept this. I definitely miss the objective C runtime API

Comment: I don't think this would work if a class is not a subclass of NSObject, will give it a try

Comment: This works for me, but it is slow. In the debugger it takes 2 or 3 seconds to execute this line of code.

Comment: Check the other answer. I'm not sure it was available when the question was asked, but now it's definitely the way to go.

Comment: sorry this answer is outdated, had to select my own answer as correct :(

Answer (score 2):

**quickly in Swift:**

```
let className = String(YourClass)
```

**Extension variant** (in my opinion, it's more convenient)**:**

```
extension NSObject {
    class var string: String{
        get {
            return String(self)
        }
    }
}

//using:
let className = YourClass.string
```